# PHP / Ajax Contact Form Redirecting to PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm in the middle of developing a contact form for a portfolio I'm working on and when I click the submit button to send the message, instead of displaying the bootstrap alert message below the form, the page redirects to the PHP file.

I'm receiving the email in my inbox from the form after submitting valid details but even though I'm using ajax I'm still getting redirected.

Example at http://nickcookweb.co.uk/#contact.

EDIT: preventDefault(); doesn't seem to be working at all.

HTML:

```
<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name (Required)" required/>

    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email (Required)" required/>

    <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Contact Number"/>

    <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message (Required)" required></textarea>

    <button type="submit" id="sendButton" class="button">Send<span class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left:6px; top:2px"></span></button>

</form>

<div id="contactSuccess" class="alert alert-success">
    <span>
        <p>Message sent successfully.</p>
    </span>
</div>

<div id="contactError" class="alert alert-danger">
    <span>
        <p>There was an error sending your message. Please try again.</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$to = "contact@nickcookweb.co.uk"; 

$from = $_REQUEST['email']; 

$name = $_REQUEST['name']; 

$message = $_REQUEST['message']; 

$headers = "From: $from"; 

$subject = "New Message via Portfolio"; 

$fields = array(); 

$fields{"name"} = "name"; 

$fields{"email"} = "email"; 

$fields{"tel"} = "tel"; 

$fields{"message"} = "message";

$body = "Details:"; 

foreach($fields as $a => $b) {   

    $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); 

}

$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
$('#contactForm').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        tel: {
            required: true
        },
        message: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Please provide your name",
            minlength: "Your name must be at least 2 characters long"
        },
        email: {
            required: "Please provide your email address"
        },
        message: {
            required: "Please enter a message",
            minlength: "Your message must be at least 10 character long"
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            type:"POST",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            url:"contact.php",
            success: function() {
                $('#contactForm :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                    $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                    $('#contactSuccess').fadeIn();
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                    $('#contactError').fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourButton').on('click', function{ 
  event.preventDefault();
  //do your ajax and on success show msg
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this locally (without an actual `contact.php`) but it is working locally.

```js
$('#form').validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
      url: form.action,
      type: form.method,
      data: $(form).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="form">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input name="name" type="text" required="" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a button with `type="button"` or add a call to 'preventDefault()' to avoid submitting the form.

Comment: Tried the type="button" and didn't work. Where would I add the preventDefault() in the JS code

Comment: just add attribute to ur form as onsubmit="return false" so it will not submit as usual.

Comment: Munish, that doesn't work. It just stops the form from submitting altogether

Answer (score -1):

Just add this attribute to ur form to prevent default action.

```
<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return false">
```

Comment: While this is a valid example. You should consider separating form and function. This will help in the longer term from a maintenance perspective.

Comment: This also doesn't work. It just stops the form from submitting altogether

Comment: hmm gud. now put ur ajax function in .submit function.   as $('#contactForm').submit(funtion(){

Comment: What? Don't know exactly what you mean but I've included ajaxSubmit within the submitHandler function

Comment: if ur submitHandler working then it should submit ur form .

Comment: The form submits fine without the attribute you suggested. That attribute just stops the form from working completely

Comment: but the submit action is default action thats why it is reloading the page which should not. Just prevent default action to work ajax exactly